# Member functions not getting inherited in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following code has three classes. `account`, `savings`(derived), `current`(derived). But three of the memberfunctions from the base class are not getting inherited. This is the error what I get. Is it possible doing without using virtual functions

> ```
> In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
> classes.hpp:96:30: error: no ‘void savingsAccount::deposit()’ member function declared in class ‘savingsAccount’
>  void savingsAccount::deposit()
>                               ^
> classes.hpp:105:31: error: no ‘void savingsAccount::withdraw()’ member function declared in class ‘savingsAccount’
>  void savingsAccount::withdraw()
>                                ^
> classes.hpp:130:31: error: no ‘void savingsAccount::display()’ member function declared in class ‘savingsAccount’
>  void savingsAccount:: display()
>                                ^
> classes.hpp:181:30: error: no ‘void currentAccount::deposit()’ member function declared in class ‘currentAccount’
>  void currentAccount::deposit()
>                               ^
> classes.hpp:190:31: error: no ‘void currentAccount::withdraw()’ member function declared in class ‘currentAccount’
>  void currentAccount::withdraw()
>                                ^
> classes.hpp:220:31: error: no ‘void currentAccount::display()’ member function declared in class ‘currentAccount’
>  void currentAccount:: display()
> ```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#define MAX 50

#ifndef classes_h
#define classes_h

using namespace std;
class account
{
    protected:
        char name[MAX];
        int accountNumber;
        char type[MAX];
        float balance;
        float minBalance;
        static int Customers;   
    public:
        account();  
        account(char*,int);

        void deposit();     
         void withdraw();   
         void display();
         int getAccountNumber();
        static void numberOfCustomers();

};

account::account(char* name, int accountNumber) 
{
    strcpy(this->name,name);
    this->accountNumber=accountNumber;
    //strcpy(this->type,type);
    this->balance=0;
    Customers++;
}

int account::Customers=0;
void account ::numberOfCustomers()
{
    cout<<"Total number of customer-------->"<<Customers;
}

void account::display()
{

}

/********************************
//Savings Account class
********************************/

class savingsAccount: public account
{
    protected:
        float minBalance; 
    //  float rate;
    public:
        savingsAccount();
        savingsAccount(char*,int);
        savingsAccount(account&);   //Copy Constructor
/*      void deposit();     //user
        void withdraw();    //user
        void display();     //user
*/      int getAccountNumber();
};



savingsAccount::savingsAccount(char* name, int accountNumber):account(name,accountNumber)
{
    minBalance=0;
    strcpy(type,"savings");
}


savingsAccount::savingsAccount(account& tp):account(tp)
{
    minBalance=0;   
    strcpy(type,"savings");
}



int savingsAccount::getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}       




void savingsAccount::deposit()
{
    float amount;
    cout<<"Enter the amount needs to be deposited"<<endl;
    cin >> amount;
    balance=balance+amount;
}


void savingsAccount::withdraw()
{
    float amount ; 
    if(balance ==0)
    {
        cout<<"Account balance is Nil"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the amount yout would like to withdraw"<<endl;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>amount;
        if(balance-amount<0)
        {
            cout<<"insufficient funds, try some less amount\n";

        }
        else
        {
            balance=balance-amount;
            return ;
        }
    }
}

void savingsAccount:: display()
{
    cout<<"Account Number"<<accountNumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Name-->"<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Accounttype-->Savings"<<endl;
    cout<<"Balance-->"<<balance<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Balance -->"<<minBalance;

}

/***********************************
//Current Account class
************************************/
class currentAccount: public account
{
    protected:
        float minBalance;
    public:
        currentAccount();
        currentAccount(char*,int);
        currentAccount(account&);
/*      void deposit();
        void withdraw();
        void display();
*/      int getAccountNumber();

};

/*
currentAccount::currentAccount(char* name, int accountNumber):account((char*)name,accountNumber,"current account")
{
     minBalance=1000;
     balance=1000;
}
*/
currentAccount::currentAccount(char* name, int accountNumber):account(name,accountNumber)
{
    minBalance=0;
    strcpy(type,"Current");
}


currentAccount::currentAccount(account& tp):account(tp)
{
    minBalance=0;   
    strcpy(type,"Current");
}




void currentAccount::deposit()
{
    float amount;
    cout<<"Enter the amount needs to be deposited"<<endl;
    cin >> amount;
    balance=balance+amount;
}


void currentAccount::withdraw()
{
    float amount ; 
    if(balance ==0)
    {
        cout<<"Account balance is Nil"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the amount yout would like to withdraw"<<endl;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>amount;
        if(balance-amount<0)
        {
            cout<<"insufficient funds, try some less amount\n";

        }
        else
        {
            balance=balance-amount;
            return ;
        }
    }
    if(balance-amount<1000)
    {
        cout<<"Please keep the balance above minimum balance ";
    }

}

void currentAccount:: display()
{
    cout<<"Account Number"<<accountNumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Name-->"<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Accounttype-->Current Account"<<endl;
    cout<<"Balance-->"<<balance<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum Balance -->"<<minBalance;

}

int currentAccount::getAccountNumber()
{
    return accountNumber;
}       

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
void savingsAccount:: display(){/* rest here */}
```

you are telling the compiler to implement the definition of a member function called `savingsAccount::display()`. However you don't specify that you have this member function in your derived class declarations. Since you overloaded it, **you need to add its signature to the derived classes**, like

```
class savingsAccount: public account
{
    /* virtual */ void display() /* override */; // probably you want this virtual in the base class
    // the rest
};
```

otherwise the compiler only knows that there exists a base version, i.e. `account::display()`. So the compiler is indeed right telling you that there is no `savingsAccount::display()` member function, as you only have `account::display()`, i.e. the member function of the base class.

Your whole issue can be simplified to

```
struct X
{
    void f();
};

struct Y: X
{
    // void f(); 
};

// error if you don't add the signature in Y,
// there is no Y::f(), only the X::f() inherited part
void Y::f(){} 

int main(){}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ac6c3654be2c753)

PS: You probably want to make those functions `virtual` too (and also add `const` to the ones that don't modify your member variables), so you have proper overriding, otherwise your derived member won't behave as you want when you have a class hierarchy controlled by a pointer-to-base.

PSS: put

```
#ifndef classes_h
#define classes_h
```

at the very beginning of your header, before any `#include`.

Comment: No, you *don't* need to redeclare a function in the derived class to inherit from the parent.

Comment: @MarkRansom You need to if you provide a definition for it in the derived class, but fail to provide the prototype, as OP did, see e.g. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40cd6c6e006a7369). Maybe I wasn't too clear in my answer, I am not saying that you need to redeclare to inherit, I'm just saying that **if** you redeclare, then you need the signature in the derived class declaration, otherwise the compiler refers to the base member function.